# How can I get the different values from two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example:
DataFrame A is
1
2
3
4
DataFrame B is
1
5
6
4

So the differences are 2, 3, 5, 6. How can I get these values and export them to a new column?
Thanks!

Comment: does both dataframe has a single column?

Comment: We need more info about the dataframes. Do they both have the same number of columns? Do they have the same column *names*? If at least 1 of the answers is "no" then you will have to define this cases

Comment: Why not subtract one from the other and then return all the non-zero values